# Call backing bean method by reflection - JSF

Tags: java, jsf

I need to call to the backing bean but the name of the method is dynamic.
Something like:

```
rendered="#{reportController.report}.#{isRendered}"
```

While isRendered is a parameter i receive using `<f:params>` tag
Is it possible? And what is the syntax if it is.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the brace notation.

```
rendered="#{reportController.report[isRendered]}"
```